# Why applications cannot access a hardware device directly ? Why we need to switch to kernel space in order to do this?

Tags: linux, kernel, system-calls, hardware, userspace

I wondered why we need to switch to kernel space when we want to access a hardware device. I understand that sometimes, for specific actions such as memory allocation, we need to make system calls in order to switch from user space to kernel space because the operating system needs to organize everything and make a separation between processes and how they use memory and others. But why we can't directly access a hardware device ?

Comment: What would be the point of an operating system then?

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem in writing your own driver to access the hardware from User Space and plenty of documentation is available. For example, this tutorial at [xatlantis](http://www.xatlantis.ch/index.php/education/others/4-linux-driver) seems to be recent and good source.

The reason it has been designed like that is because mainly due to security reasons .Most systems I know about specifically  do not allow user programs to do I/O or to access kernel space memory. Such things would lead to wildly insecure systems, because with access to the kernel a user program could change permissions and get access to any data anywhere in the system, and presumably change it.

References:
[XATLANTIS](http://www.xatlantis.ch/index.php/education/others/4-linux-driver)
[STACKEXCHANGE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42980/can-hardware-be-accessed-directly-from-user-space#:%7E:text=Virtually%20no%20operating%20system%20newer,plenty%20of%20documentation%20is%20available.)

Answer (score 0):

A device-driver *may* choose to provide access from user processes to device registers, device memory, or both.  A common method is a device-specific service connected with an mmap() request.  Consider a frame-buffer's on-board memory, and efficiency from a user process being able to r/w that space directly.  For devices in general, notably there are security considerations and drivers that provide direct access often set limits to processes with sufficient credentials.  Files within /dev are usually set with owner/group access permissions similarly limited.